# I don't know how to change the shape of my equation to another one From $4(y/x)^3-(1/x)$ to $C = xy^3-(x^4)/4$

Tags: calculus

I have: $$C = 4\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{3}-\frac{1}{x}$$

[it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtpLW.png) \

I need it to look like this:
$$C = xy^3-\frac{x^{4}}{4}$$

[It look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ryLZ.png) 
$C$ is a constant 
$x$ and $y$ are variables.

I tried but failed multiple times to make it look like the desired answer.

All of this take place in a calculus problem that you can see in the image below.

[Here you can see from where I came up with 4(y/x)^3-1/x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiCrT.png)

Comment: The following equations don´t look equivalent to me: $$c=\frac{1}{((4v^3-1)^{\frac14}}-x  \ \Large{\not\Leftrightarrow} \normalsize \  c=(4v^3-1)^{\frac14}-\frac1x$$ The other transformations don't make it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake in the $4^{th}$ line of your solution. $e^{a+b} \ne e^a+e^b$.

$-\frac{1}{4}\ln(4v^3-1) = \ln(x) + C \Rightarrow (4v^3-1)^{-1/4} = e^{\ln x +C} = e^{\ln x}e^C = ke^{\ln x} = kx$

($k = e^C$)

So, $(4v^3 -1) = (kx)^{-4} \Rightarrow 4(\frac yx)^3-1 = k^{-4}x^{-4} \Rightarrow \boxed{k^{-4} = 4y^3x-x^4}$

You may take, $\boxed{k' = \frac{k^{-4}}4 = y^3x - \frac{x^4}4}$

Comment: Thank you!!!! So much stress gone now

Comment: You're welcome!